# bash pipe construct to prepend something to the stdoutput of previous command

Tags: command-line, bash, posix

I want to use sendmail to send me stuff and want to do it in a oneliner.

```
echo "mail content" | sendmail emailataddres.com
```

Sends it without subject.

The subject line must come before the Mail content,
so I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
echo "mail content" | prepend "Subject: All that matters" | sendmail emailataddres.com
```

sed and awk tend to be really awkward to use and remember.

*EDIT*:Just to clarify: echo "Mail content" is just an illustrating example. I need to be able to prepend stuff to stdout streams from any source. e.g.: ifconfig, zcat, etc..

Comment: `echo -e "Subject: All that matters\nmail content"`? Or more platform agnostic: `printf 'Subject: %s\n%s\n' "All that matters" "mail content"`. You could also write a small script that just takes the two string arguments to make an even simpler one-liner.

Comment: Well if you add this as an answer I might accept it... :)

Comment: ah, no I don't, sorry. Please regard my edit.

Comment: What should `prepend` do? In order to know how to prepend something, you have to wait until the upstream command (e.g. `echo`) sends the EOF, so that you can insert your data ahead of it in the stream before passing it to stdout to get piped to sendmail. Sounds like a task for a shortish Ruby or Python script.

Comment: I don't have to wait. It can be inserted at the beginning of the stream.

Comment: sed worked great for me. From this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13884279/878969). `echo "input" | awk '{print "Subject: All that matters"$1}'`

Comment: A slightly different approach would be to use the `mail` command (sometimes called bsdmail) instead of `sendmail` directly. `mail` takes an optional `-s subject` option, e.g.:  `ifconfig -a | mail -s 'Current ifconfig output' me@someaddr.com`

Answer (score 57):

```
$ echo 1 | (echo 2 && cat)
2
1
```

I am pretty sure that there is a nicer solution, but this should do.

Comment: Simple, functional and demonstrated. +1

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it without the break return?

Comment: @VenomFangs Use `printf` instead of the second `echo` and you should be fine

Comment: *>Is there an easy way to do it without the break return?* - `echo -n`

Answer (score 9):

Either use what Claudius said or make your own:

### ~/bin/prepend:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -en "$@"
cat -
```

### e.g.:

```
$ echo "Splendid SUPANINJA! Let's do it!" |\
     prepend "Subject: Venetian Snares\n"

Subject: Venetian Snares
Splendid SUPANINJA! Lets do it!
```

Answer (score 6):

This is inspired by Claudius answer.

If you don't want a break return between your outputs, add the `-n` param. This will look like:

`$ echo 1 | (echo -n 2 && cat)`

Which will give:

`21`

Comment: Actually, no it won't. It gives "2\n1". You have to attach the "-n"  to the _second_ echo. Still +1. If you Correct that, I might accept it. I am not sure what's fair, since Claudius contributed the most to the solution.

Comment: Sorry, think I put the `-n` in the wrong place. Anyway, The update should give "21\n" if you want to get rid of the \n then just add a -n before the 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend to piped output using [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```bsh
$ echo "mail content" | cat <(echo "Subject: All that matters") -
Subject: All that matters
mail content
```

Answer (score 1):

From the pieces I've gathered... you could do something like this:

```
echo "Subject: All that matters
`echo "mail content"`" | sendmail blah@blahblah
```

Notice that I did not close the quotes on the first line... because not all shells translate the `\n` into a newline character... but I have yet to find one that wont process an actual newline inside the quotes.

When a command is enclosed in the ` character, it will be executed and the output will be injected in-place.  Keep in mind that this bit of code is a bit dangerous as it is possible to inject additional commands inline that could easily compromise your system...

****edit**** Following advise of Claudius, a cleaner option would look like this:

```
echo -e "Subject: All that matters \n $(echo "mail content") |sendmail blah@blahblah
```

Even with that template, it could be exploited.

Comment: It is usually nicer to use `$()` rather than `` as it is supposed to be more portable (and also more readable). Furthermore, you can use `echo`’s `-e` option to make it translate newlines (`echo -e "1\n2"`) or just use printf as suggested by Daniel in the first comment.

Comment: Immediately after posting my answer... I read yours & like it better.   Good points.